# Excel Sequential Numbering Based On Cell Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to generate a sequential number in col C based on the value in col B. The number needs to follow the text System and each time the sequence number in col B resets, I need the numbering to reset but start at the next nearest base number, as shown below

Example data...

```
A ¦ B ¦ C
1   1   End Item
2   2   System10
3   3   System11
4   3   System12
5   2   System20
6   3   System21
7   3   System22
8   2   System30
9   3   System31
```

I have tried the following formula =IF(B1=B2, "System" & C1+1, "System" & 1)

However this doesn't give me the numbers starting at 10.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In that regard your first `System` without any numbering doesn't make sense > Going from 0-10

Comment: System is top level and numbering starts at 10 for first sub system.

Comment: Top level will be 1 and each sub system will be at level 2. Level 3 will be children of sub system.

Comment: Still makes no sense from row 1 (at least to me). What makes sense would be in Row 1 > `System10` and go from there.

Comment: Row 1 (top level) isn't a system. All levels below it are. I can see why it doesn't make sense. Row 1 col C needs to be changed to "End Item".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first cut at this, you could try:

```
=IF(C1="End Item","System10",IF(B2>=B1,"System"&RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-6)+1,"System"&ROUNDUP(RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-6),-1)))
```

This does allow for numbers of more than two digits, but doesn't increase to the next multiple of ten if the current number is an exact multiple of ten.

One way of getting round this would be to add a small increment:

```
=IF(C1="End Item","System10",IF(B2>=B1,"System"&RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-6)+1,"System"&ROUNDUP(RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-6)+0.1,-1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, have been away for a few days. Thank you for the formula, seems to work perfectly on my data.